# bash/expect/loop - how to loop a simple bash script doing telnet

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, telnet, expect

I would like to run this script in a loop.

What is needs to do is read a file with in that file IP addresses like:

```
10.0.0.0
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
```

And run this script on every ip listed above here.

This is what i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet 10.0.0.0
expect "User Name :"
send "username\r"

expect "Password  :"
send "password\r"
expect ">"
send "4\r"
expect "*#"
exit
```

How do i get the script above working every IP in a txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file within your expect script.

Open the file and assign the file descriptor to a variable, read each line and execute the above code you wrote.

```
set fildes [open "myhosts.txt" r]
set ip [gets $fildes]
while {[string length $ip] > 0} {

    spawn telnet $ip
    expect "User Name :"
    send "username\r"

    expect "Password  :"
    send "password\r"
    expect ">"
    send "4\r"
    expect "*#"
    exit
    set ip [gets $fildes]
}
close $fildes
```

Comment: the scripts works nice! But it only uses the first IP from myhosts.txt and it doesn't uses the ip's under the first line in myhosts.txt

But the login is working

Comment: Sorry it works i had that exit that to remove :D
Thank you very much :)

Comment: It exits because I inherited your typo error. The line that says exit should be send "exit\r" because the intent of that line is to tell the spawned telnet to exit. But the typo error is telling the script to exit.

Comment: change `exit` to `send "exit\r"; expect eof; exp_close; wait`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert with `expect`, but the first thing you need to do is change your expect script to accept arguments. It should work like this (looks like you'll need `-f` in `#!/usr/bin/expect`):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set ip [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet $ip
...
```

Then you can simply iterate over the list of your IPs in your bash script:

```
while read ip ; do
    myExpectScript $ip
done < list_of_ip.txt
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a comment on @user3088572's answer. The idiomatic way to read a file line by line is:

```
set fildes [open "myhosts.txt" r]
while {[gets $fildes ip] != -1} {
    # do something with $ip
}
close $fildes
```